# python json Exception: KeyError 0

Tags: python, json, keyerror

I am trying in a loop that I will create later to give out the names for an Api Post request (here for testing as print) but I always get the error Exception:KeyError 0.

Can someone help there?

file.json:

```
{ "_meta": {
        "Example1": {
            "00000001": {
                    "name": "Test-01",
                },
            "00000002": {
                    "name": "Test-02"
                },
            },
}
```

```
import json

data = json.load(open("file.json"))

name = data["_meta"]["Example1"][0]["name"]


print(f"Name: {name}")
```

Exception: KeyError 0

Problem:

I want to use an API with POST to create objects in a database. For this purpose I want to build a loop with Python that gives the json keys (00001,00002,...) one by one to the API.
Like:

```
i = 0
while i < 10
data["_meta"]["Example1"][i]["name"]
API
i = i + 1
```

But my Problem is that 000001 is only an Example the real KeyName is a word such like

```
{ "_meta": {
        "Example1": {
            "Beta1231": {
                    "name": "Test-01",
                },
            "Frog00123": {
                    "name": "Test-02"
                },
            },
}
```

Comment: `data["_meta"]["Example1"]` is a dictionary, not a list. It doesn't have a `0` key but `"00000001"` and `"00000002"`, so `KeyError` is expected.

Comment: @alec_djinn Do you have any idea how the [0] can be a variable and not a fixed value?

Comment: I don't quite get what you are asking. Something like this `k="00000001"` and then `name = data["_meta"]["Example1"][k]["name"]` ? What is your goal? Please try describing your problem in a more exhaustive way. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @alec_djinn  In the Topic beacuse the Code was not shown right in a comment

Comment: It is not clear if you know the keys or not. In your example, it looks like you know them because you can get them from `data["_meta"]["Example1"].keys()`. So, again, I don't quite get what is the problem here.

Comment: @alec_djinn i have open up a new question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305952/python-json-dict-variable) maybe you unsterand it there and coud help me

Answer (score 1):

the `exemple` field is a `dict` not a `list` so instead of

> `data["_meta"]["Example1"][0]["name"]`

you need to pass a keyname

```
data["_meta"]["Example1"]["key_name"]["name"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I needed a variable key name there.