# Python Json dict Variable

Tags: python, json

I am trying in a loop that I will create later to give out the names(single) for an Api Post request (here for testing as print) and Change the Vaule oft the Variable in each turn of the loop. Now im running in Exception:KeyError 0.

My question is. Is there an Variable that i can use for `[0]` (Key_name)

Can someone help there?

file.json:

(Shortened, the real file is much longer)

```
{ "_meta": {
        "Example1": {
            "00000001": {
                    "name": "Test-01",
                },
            "00000002": {
                    "name": "Test-02"
                },
            },
}
```

```
import json

data = json.load(open("file.json"))

name = data["_meta"]["Example1"][0]["name"]


print(f"Name: {name}")
```

Exception: KeyError 0

Edit

```
        "Example1": {
            "00000001": {
                    "name": "Test-01",

                },
            "00000002": {
                    "name": "Test-02"
                    "uuid": "Test-uuid"
                    "config": {
                          "ipAdresse": "Test-Ip"
                     },
                },
            },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is the `[0]`, the value for the `Example1` element is not a list but a dict. Try using `dict.items()`

```py
for key, value in data["_meta"]["Example1"].items():
    print(f"Key: {key}\nName: {value['name']}")
```

---

**EDIT** for the comment below:

So you need to test if a key exists inside the dict items to avoid the `key not found` errors. You can do so by simply checking `if keyname in dict`

See the extended example below...

```py
data = {
    "_meta":{
        "Example1":{
            "00000001":{
                "name":"Test-01"
            },
            "00000002":{
                "name":"Test-02",
                "uuid":"Test-uuid",
                "config":{
                    "ipAdresse":"Test-Ip"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for key, value in data["_meta"]["Example1"].items():
    print(f"Key: {key}\n  Name: {value['name']}")
    # check if the key exists. fe 00000001 does not have the uuid nor config key
    if "uuid" in value:
        print(f"  uuid: {value['uuid']}")
    if "config" in value and "ipAdresse" in value["config"]:
        print(f"  ipAdresse: {value['config']['ipAdresse']}")
```

output

```
Key: 00000001
  Name: Test-01
Key: 00000002
  Name: Test-02
  uuid: Test-uuid
  ipAdresse: Test-Ip
```

Comment: Thank you that workt for the vaule name. But when my json have more values like(i have editet my post up) what must i do to print ipAddress or uuid. Because when i cange the value 'name' to uuid I get an KeyError

Comment: see my updated answer. Note that the provided JSON was a bit malformed...

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. Yes the json was not the original I just edited it so my problem was shown corret